# replace text string in one cell with another based on condition

Tags: replace

I want the content of cell A3 to be replaced by "Other" if it is *not* "text A" or "text B".  I tried this suggestion by someone   **=IF(A4="C", "Other", A4)**  it works but it does *not* replace the text in cell A3...instead it only returns "Other" in the cell where the formula is typed. So the formula itself does the job of returning Other if A4="C", but it does not replace the text string in A4 with "Other" which is what I want to happen.

Can anyone suggest something that actually works when you try the above scenario? Thanks.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.